# Dynamic form's javascript not working when removed { } from select tag-Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

I have a **form with a gender field** in rails as:

```
<%= f.select :gender, ["Male","Female"],{class: "gender"} %>
```

i also tried it with this:

```
<%= f.select :gender, ["Male","Female"],{class: "gender"},onclick: "categorychange" %>
```

But it's not working. Now when I Tried:

```
<%= f.select :gender, ["Male","Female"],{},{class: "gender"} %>
```

That's working all fine. which I found here.[image]
I didn't get what the **{ }** stands for.

and for different gender **I have different corresponding field** to show which are as follows:

```
<div class="male">
//male fields here//
</div>  

<div class="female">
//female fields here//
</div>
```

I have the **javascript** as:

```
function categorychange(){
var val = $(this).val();
var gender = $(this).parent().find(".gender")
if (gender.val() == 'Male')
{
  $(this).parent().find('.male').show();  
  $(this).parent().find('.female').hide();
}
else if (gender.val()=='Female')
{
 $(this).parent().find('.male').hide();  
 $(this).parent().find('.female').show();
}
```

But the javascript is not working. It shows both the div's.

Comment: What element calls `categorychange`?

Comment: @Musa okay now I called the categorychange function from the f.select field as `<%= f.select :gender, ["male","female"],onclick: "categorychange" %>` But it's still not working.

Comment: The rails select requires 5 different arguments. The {} is to provide options for the select. For example { prompt: 'Choose a gender' }.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var select_gender = $('.gender')
select_gender.change(function(){
if (select_gender.val() == 'Male')
{
  $('.male').show();  
  $('.female').hide();
}
else if (select_gender.val()=='Female')
{
 $('.male').hide();  
 $('.female').show();
}}
```

Rather than using onclick on the view, try onchange event in the javascript for the select input.